# How do I free a boost::mpi::request?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I'm trying to get MPI to disconnect a communicator, which is a tetchy business - I've put together a demo below. I've got two versions of the same idea, listening for an int, one using MPI_IRecv, and one using a boost::mpi::request.

You'll note when using mpiexec -n 2 on this program that version A will happily disconnect and exit, but version B will not. Is there some trick to MPI_Request_free-ing a boost::mpi::request? That seems to be the difference here. If it matters, I'm using MSVC and MSMPI, and Boost 1.62.

```
#include "boost/mpi.hpp"
#include "mpi.h"

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm regional;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &regional);
    boost::mpi::communicator comm = boost::mpi::communicator(regional, boost::mpi::comm_attach);
    if (comm.rank() == 1)
    {
        int q;

        //VERSION A:
//      MPI_Request n;
//      int j = MPI_Irecv(&q, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, regional, &n);
//      MPI_Cancel(&n);
//      MPI_Request_free(&n);

        //VERSION B:

//      boost::mpi::request z = comm.irecv<int>(1, 0, q);
//      z.cancel();

    }
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&regional);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Did I find a bug? I doubt I'm deep in the code.

Comment: comm_duplicate greatly improves the situation but you still should be able to do this.

Comment: Version B returns without problem on Linux and boost 1.61.

Comment: @Shibli most likely depends on the MPI implementation. Example code does not block here for OpenMPI 1.10. But it's easy to see that it's incorrect from the boost sources / MPI standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it guess it's not a bug if it's documented: [`MPI_Request_free` is unsupported by Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping).

Now going back to MPI itself:

> A call to `MPI_CANCEL` marks for cancellation a pending, nonblocking communication operation (send or receive). The cancel call is local. It returns immediately, possibly before the communication is actually cancelled. It is still necessary to call `MPI_REQUEST_FREE`, `MPI_WAIT` or `MPI_TEST` (or any of the derived operations) with the cancelled request as
>   argument after the call to `MPI_CANCEL`. **If a communication is marked for cancellation, then a `MPI_WAIT` call for that communication is guaranteed to return, irrespective of the activities of other processes** (i.e., `MPI_WAIT` behaves as a local function);

That means, just:

```
z.cancel();
z.wait();
```

and you should be fine.

Now, IMHO this is a bad waste of proper RAII by Boost.MPI.

Comment: Ah, got it. That makes no sense whatsoever, but OK.

Comment: If it's any reconciliation - Boost.MPI regularly surprises me with stupid big and little issues and by breaking stuff that works just fine with normal MPI. Or is there an aspect about the standard that doesn't seem sensible to you?

Comment: Nah, I get what normal MPI is doing, the whole cancel and wait thing was a bit of a surprise. Boost MPI is lovely but will sometimes wake you up.