# Boost MPI doesn't free resources when listening for lists?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

This is a follow-on question to [How do I free a boost::mpi::request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078901/how-do-i-free-a-boostmpirequest) . I'm noting odd behavior when listening for lists rather than individual items. Is this my error or an error in boost? I'm using MSVC and MSMPI, Boost 1.62. I'm pretty sure that it's not behaving properly on the wait for a cancelled job.

If you try version B with mpiexec -n 2 then you get a clean exit - if you try version A, it hangs indefinitely. Do you all see this as well? Is this a bug?

```
#include "boost/mpi.hpp"
#include "mpi.h"
#include <list>
#include "boost/serialization/list.hpp"

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm regional;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &regional);
    boost::mpi::communicator comm = boost::mpi::communicator(regional, boost::mpi::comm_attach);
    if (comm.rank() == 1)
    {


        //VERSION A:
        std::list<int> q;
        boost::mpi::request z = comm.irecv<std::list<int>>(1, 0, q);
        z.cancel();
        z.wait();


        //VERSION B:
//      int q;
//      boost::mpi::request z = comm.irecv<int>(1, 0, q);
//      z.cancel();
//      z.wait();

    }
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&regional);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An even more interesting case is possible in which you have a struct using friend class boost::serialization::access - if you use BOOST_IS_MPI_DATATYPE, the behavior differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in Boost.MPI.

For serialized types, like `std::list`, the cancel is forwarded from [`request::cancel()`](https://github.com/boostorg/mpi/blob/boost-1.64.0/src/request.cpp#L109) to [`request::handle_serialized_irecv`](https://github.com/boostorg/mpi/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/mpi/communicator.hpp#L1550), which does not specify a proper handling for `ra_cancel`.

Comment: I wonder if we can cancel by doing this: `for (auto& r: z.m_requests) { r = MPI_REQUEST_NULL; }`

Comment: I think you need to consider the different combinations / states of `m_requests`.